# MySQL: 'user'@'hostname' vs 'user'@'IPaddress'

Tags: mysql, users

I needed an user to be able to log in on our MySQL server 5.6 from machine foobarhost, IP 10.11.12.13.

Therefore I created a user `'joe'@'foobarhost'` but he was unable to log in.  I had to create an user `'joe'@'10.11.12.13'` and this time worked fine.

**My question**: how does MySQL handle hostnames vs IP addresses concerning users?

MySQL [sorts the user table before checking for a match](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connection-access.html), using IP addresses and hostnames as the most-specific values to match to.  However, the docs do not specify what takes precedence - hostname or IP.  Does MySQL attempt a hostname resolution and, if it fails, performs a check on the IP?

What is the recommended usage for the user table: specify only IP addresses, hostnames, or both (as I did in the example above)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem before, and after long investigation I found out sometimes MySQL can not resolve any issue related to `DNS` by default, so I did the following: edited hosts file ( can be found under Linux `/etc/hosts`, for Windows `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) and added ip and `hostname` for the client machine,in your example its

```
10.11.12.13 foobarhost
```

then save and close ( note Windows will require reboot before taking any effect), you may need to add the following parameters `--skip-name-resolve` and\or `--skip-host-cache` .